# Filter base entity from child entities' properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have been looking for a solution for days now.

I have eight entities in my application, a base and seven entities that inherits from this base entity. Some of the child entities have same properties.

```
public class LogEntry(){
    public int LogEntryId{get;set;}
    public string ...
}

public class TestEntry : LogEntry{
   ....
   public string SomeProperty{get;set;} //SomePropertyThatIsNotInBaseClass
   ....
}
public class XEntry : LogEntry{
   ....
   public string SomeProperty{get; set;}
   ....
}
```

I am trying to filter base entity by this SomeProperty. I am trying to a query like

```
var value = Db.LogEntry.Where(i=>i.SomePropery == "some string");
```

It is not allowed. I can only getwhat I want by

```
IQueryable<LogEntry> first = Db.LogEntry.OfType<TestEntry>.Where(i=>i.SomeProperty == "...");
IQueryable<LogEntry> second = Db.LogEntry.OfType<XEntry>.Where(i=>i.SomeProperty == "...");
...
```

And concatenate them at the end. Is there more clever way to do than this method? Extension methods etc...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do *all* of the subclasses have `SomeProperty` on them? If not, it wouldn't be possible to know what to do with the rest of them that don't have the property.

Comment: What Ocelot20 is alluding to is that it is impossible to write a query that is filtering on a property defined in a derived type. You can only query the properties that are defined in the base type unless you query the specific type like you have done in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

Looking at your example more closely, I don't think what you are trying to do is possible. If you are writing a query against the BASE entity type, then you can only query fields that are defined in the base type.

Since "SomeProperty" is not defined in LogEntry, you cannot write this query:

```
var logEntries = db.LogEntry.Where(r => r.SomeProperty == "foo");
```

Because SomeProperty is not defined in the LogEntry class.

If you want to write queries against the base class then you need to do something like the following:

```
public class TPTContext : DbContext
{
    public TPTContext() : base("name=TPT")
    { }

    public DbSet<BillingDetail> BillingDetails { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BillingDetail
{
    public int BillingDetailId { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

[Table("BankAccounts")]
public class BankAccount : BillingDetail
{
    public string BankName { get; set; }
    public string Swift { get; set; }
}

[Table("CreditCards")]
public class CreditCard : BillingDetail
{
    public int CardType { get; set; }
    public string ExpiryMonth { get; set; }
    public string ExpiryYear { get; set; }
}
```

I wrote the following query against the base class:

```
TPTContext db = new TPTContext();

var allAccounts = db.BillingDetails.Where(b => b.Owner == "boran");
var bankAccounts = allAccounts.OfType<BankAccount>();
var creditCards = allAccounts.OfType<CreditCard>();
```

Everything seems to work fine for me.

Comment: I think the problem is that his base class isn't abstract, and his subclasses may not all implement something like `Owner` at all.

Comment: You don't have to have an abstract base class for TPT to work IIRC. Owner is a property on the base class so no matter what type you are querying it is always available.

Comment: Right, but if you look at his example, his base class doesn't have the property that he's searching on.

Comment: Ahh nice catch. Yeah that scenario is impossible.