# Access child entities' properties from base entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

More than one year later from my first question on SO ([Filter base entity from child entities' properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101971/filter-base-entity-from-child-entities-properties)), I have a similar problem.

I have an abstract base type

```
public abstract class Base{
}
```

I have some child entities that inherits from this Base Type

```
public class Child1 : Base{
    public virtual NavigationProperty NavigationProperty {get; set; }
    public int NavigationPropertyId {get; set}
}

public class Child2 : Base{
    public virtual NavigationProperty NavigationProperty {get; set; }
}
```

The child entities all have NavigationProperty property. And the NavigationProperty class is like

```
 public class NavigationProperty{
    public virtual ICollection<Child1> Child1s {get; set;}
    public virtual Child2 Child2s {get; set;}
 }
```

There one-to-one mapping between Child2 and NavigationProperty; one-to-many relationship between Child1 and NavigationProperty. In order to these mapping to work i am using TPT. My first question is, can I move

```
  public NavigationProperty NavigationProperty {get; set; }
```

to Base class?

I am trying this for a whole day and did not have any success. If it is not possible can i at least access the NavigationProperty from the base type. After all the childs have this property, I tried something like

```
 public abstract class Base{
      public abstract NavigationProperty NavigationProperty {get; set; }
 }
 ....
 public abstract class Child2{
      public override NavigationProperty NavigationProperty {get; set; }
 }
```

But entity framework gives the following error.

```
 Sequence contains more than one matching element
```

I can use something like

```
   public abstract class Base{
      public abstract NavigationProperty GetNavigationProperty();
   }

  public abstract class Child2{
      public override NavigationProperty NavigationProperty {get; set; }
      public override NavigationProperty GetNavigationProperty(){
           return NavigationProperty;
      }
 }
```

But I do not want to introduce these extra methods. Are they any way to achieve this more elegantly?

Edit:

I forgot to mention that I have already tried putting `[NotMapped]` attribute.  I guess EF `[NotMapped]` attribute is inherited too so the child properties are not mapped too.

I do not expect to Linq-to-Entites to work. I do not want to be able to query base entities with navigation properties. I simply want to get rid of GetNavigationProperty and SetNavigationProperty methods. So when i try to access NavigationProperty from base class it should be loaded into memory, that's all. However, after a week of effort, I do not think it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I move
>
> `public NavigationProperty NavigationProperty {get; set; }`
>
> to Base class?

No, because the inverse properties in entity `NavigationProperty` refer to `Child1` and `Child2`, not to `Base`. Navigation properties always must be properties of the *declared* type and cannot be moved to a base type in the inheritance chain.

For the second problem you could try to exclude the abstract navigation property from the mapping:

```
public abstract class Base {
    [NotMapped]
    public abstract NavigationProperty NavigationProperty {get; set; }
}
```

(or `modelBuilder.Entity<Base>().Ignore(b => b.NavigationProperty);` with Fluent API).

You won't be able though to use `Base.NavigationProperty` in any queries because you can't use not mapped properties with LINQ-to-Entities.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT x1** Updated code to avoid literal strings for property name

A little bit of reflection seems to do the job. Class setup;

```
public class NavigationProperty
{
    public NavigationProperty(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Base
{
    public NavigationProperty NavigationProperty
    {
        get
        {
            string propertyName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.Replace("get_", string.Empty);
            PropertyInfo property = this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
            if (property != null)
            {
                nav = (NavigationProperty)property.GetValue(this, new object[] { });
            }

            return nav;
        }
        set
        {
            string propertyName = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.Replace("set_", string.Empty);
            PropertyInfo property = this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
            if (property != null)
            {
                property.SetValue(this, value, new object[] { });
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Child1 : Base {
    public NavigationProperty NavigationProperty { get; set; }
    public int NavigationPropertyId { get; set; }
}

public class Child2 : Base{
    public NavigationProperty NavigationProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And in your code;

```
Child1 c1 = new Child1() { NavigationProperty = new NavigationProperty("child1Value") };
Child2 c2 = new Child2() { NavigationProperty = new NavigationProperty("child2Value") };
Base somebase = c1;
NavigationProperty childNav = somebase.NavigationProperty;
// childNav.Name now contains "child1Value"
```

Does this meet your requirements? It's a little more clunky than using an `abstract` method but it at least means you don't have to refactor every child class

Comment: +1 for effort. However, Entity Framework does not allow `public NavigationProperty NavigationProperty` on the base class. `[not mapped]` attributes are inherited. If [not mapped] is not used, it gives `Sequence contains more than one matching element` error. So the base property name should be different. Even with this way, property names passed as strings is unacceptable for our project. When I asked the  question, I thought this behaviour should be possible without the need for any of these hacks. But I guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Short of finding support in Entity Framework for your scenario, you could try this:

```
public interface IHasNavigationProperty {
    NavigationProperty NavigationProperty { get; }
}

public class Child1 : Base, IHasNavigationProperty {
    public NavigationProperty NavigationProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Base {
    public void AMethodThatDoesStuff() {
        if (this is IHasNavigationProperty) {
            var navigationProperty = ((IHasNavigationProperty)this).NavigationProperty;

            /* do stuff with NavigationProperty */
        }
    }
}
```